# How to create/call a method for testing

Tags: java, methods

```
public class CMRandomNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    int days;
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 1024 + 1);

    String RandomNumber;

    int y;

    int guess = 2;
    // Define Table display
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    model.addColumn("Your Guess ");
    model.addColumn("Try Number ");
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Try to guess a number between 1-1024! \nPlease enter a number for guess");

    for (int e = 1; e < guess; e++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] { Integer.toString(e), "" + (input) });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        guess = guess + 1;
        {

        // I wanted to make a method so I can add this to my Tests
        // below,

        if (input == null) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a  number between 1-1024! .");
        }

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException a) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a  number between 1-1024! .");
        }

        y = Integer.parseInt(input);

        // I need to place my method here, so I can check for input
        // every try
        if (y < 1 && y > 1024) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a  number between 1-1024! .");

        }

        if (y < randomNum) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Your guess was too small! \nPlease enter a number for guess" + guess);

            guess = guess + 1;
        }

        if (y > randomNum) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Your guess was too big! \nPlease enter a number for guess" + guess);
            guess = guess + 1;
        }

        if (y == randomNum) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "You guessed the correct number in " + guess + " tries, \n Congratulations, you win!");
        }

        }

    }
    }
}
```

> I would like to have my try catch block to run every time. 
>   1Catch the String,
>   2 attempt to parse it as an int 
>   If the input is valid,
>   Run it against my tests. 
>   I am experimenting  code from a classmate who posted last assignments solution I have ran into problems on defining the method.

I have considered that I placed my try catch method in the wrong place. It only ran once, when I test it again it "breaks" the program.

Instead of a method, should I attempt a for loop that ensures the try catch is executed?Thanks for you input.

Comment: please format your code properly, it will make people more likely to help you

Comment: I think what you need is rather a loop. Your user may enter input that cannot be parsed or is outside the range 1 through 1024 many times, so you need to keep asking in a loop until you get an input that can be parsed to a number within the range.

Comment: I find it unclear what you mean by “for testing”. For testing that the user input is valid — or for testing your program?

Answer (score 1):

How to create a method

```
public void mymethod(){
     //code goes here
}
```

How to call a method

```
    Classname obj = new Classname();
    obj.mymethod();
```

This is making a instance of your class else if donot want to make a instance of your class just

```
public static void mymethod() {
      //code here
}
```

When you call just

```
mymethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make while loop in order to "catch" your string. Do:

> ```
>     boolean is_valid = false;
>     while(is_valid == false) {
>         try { 
>             ... code ...
>             is_valid = true;
>         }
>         catch { ... }
>     }
> ```

Comment: A helpful answer. The usual way to put the condition would be `while (!isValid)`. The exclamation mark means ‘not’. Underscore is not used in variable names, instead camel-case is.